# EmberJS: any way for {{render}}'s controller to know when view is back in the DOM?

Tags: ember.js, controller, render

I've got a Controller which backs a view that's created via {{render "foo"}}.  This Controller is a singleton because I'm not passing in a model in the {{render "foo"}} call, and {{render "foo"}} can be called from many different parts of the application.  So in other words, the view for this controller (which gets embedded via {{render}}) will be removed and added to the DOM over and over again.  Is there a way for the controller to know when the view is rendered on and removed from the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and implement the didInsertElement and willDestroyElement hooks on your Ember view. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

Then inside that implementation, you can call a function on your controller.. for example:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.get('controller').callFunctionOnController();
}
```